# PictureBox and Dispose

Tags: c#

I must delete an image file if it already exists (overwriting it) while a `PictureBox` is showing the same.
However If I try to delete the file it's blocked by `PictureBox`.
So I write the following code:

```
if (File.Exists(file))
{
   Image _tmp = (Image)current_pic.Image.Clone();                 
   current_pic.Image.Dispose();
   current_pic.Dispose();
   File.Delete(path);
   current_pic.Image = _tmp;
   current_pic.Image.Save(file, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
else
   current_pic.Image.Save(file, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

and the Image on filesystem is deleted thanks to `pic.Dispose()` but the Image is not
more showed inside the `PictureBox`.
Maybe does `Dispose()` method invalidate `PictureBox`?

Comment: do not call `current_pic.Dispose();` if you plan to further use `current_pic`

Comment: System.Drawing.Image keeps the file locked when you open it, just read the entire file in memory into a byte[] (or make a temporary copy on disk) then read from a MemoryStream (for byte[]) or from the copy. Original one won't be locked and you'll be able to delete it.

Comment: Oh, Clone() won't make a copy of the image data but, all memory-data will be cloned but bitmap-data will stay on disk so they'll be locked even if you dispose the original object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read a image into the picture box without locking it as shown below

```
Image img;
string file = @"d:\a.jpg";
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(file))
{
   img = new Bitmap(bmp);
   current_pic.Image = img;
}
if (File.Exists(file))
{
    File.Delete(file);
    current_pic.Image.Save(file, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
else
    current_pic.Image.Save(file, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

I have updated the code to even support the save operation.

While the previous code supported the delete even after linking the images. The stream was closed and this while saving resulted in a GDI+ error.

The newly updated code meets all your requirements as follows

- Allowing a delete of the file while the images is linked
- Save of the Image using the Image property in the Picturebox control